# Why can I still access object listing of a Google Cloud private bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, credentials

I made a bucket in cloud storage in a Google Cloud private bucket (preventing all public access). I am new to Google Cloud so this is some tests I am doing. I created service account credentials key to get storage access while developping. At some point I realise I can list the objects of the bucket using nodejs locally even if I deactivate the service account credentials in GCP console and in code.

So I am getting the credentials from somewhere else since I cant list the bucket objects on another computer...

I am trying to find where I am getting credentials from...

I deleted gcloud default configuration files.
Removed all gcloud auth accounts, no credentials when I list them.

But I can still list the private bucket objects locally in node.

There is an appengine app in this gcp project.

Here is my nodejs code:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const path=require("path");


const googleCloudProject=process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT;
const storage = new Storage({
    //keyFilename:path.join(__dirname,"./phrasal-method-392523-57b015679652.json"),
    //projectId:process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT
});

const bucketName = process.env.GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET;

async function listFiles() {
    // Lists files in the bucket
    try{
        console.log(bucketName);
        const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
        console.log(files[0].name);
    }catch(error){
        console.log("ERROR!!:"+error);
        //res.statusCode(500).send("Error occured");
    }   
  }

  
 
 
listFiles();
```

The json credentials file is commented...

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Can you run this command `gcloud auth application-default revoke` and tell me if you still have access to the bucket?

Comment: I cant anymore! Thank you very much! I will investigate about this and how it all works. I want to know how gcloud auth works to make sure everything is as secure as possible. If you want to write an answer I will mark it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to learn more about [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc) on Google Cloud

ADC is a standard mechanism used by the Google Cloud client libraries to find automatically the credentials in the runtime environment when you don't mention explicitly a service account key file. *And because you are learning Google CLoud, start by avoiding the service account key file, it's a bad practice that create security breaches in your dev cycle.*

- ADC starts by searching the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env vars to use it
- If not present, it test if the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) is present (All Google Cloud Services offer metadata server that serve credential of your runtime service account) -> Work only if you run your code on Google Cloud
- If not, it looks in the "well known location", especially to look if you performed, previously, a `gcloud auth application-default login` to create a JSON file in your current runtime environment (your workstation) with your own user credential information

---

In bonus, keep that in mind

- `gcloud auth application-default login` create a credentials file in your file system and it is used **when you run code with client libraries**
- `gcloud auth login` create a credentials file in your file system and it is used **when you use the `gcloud` command line**

Comment: Thank you very much for all the given info!